# How to compile React JS code using Craco?

Tags: reactjs, craco

I created a React JS app using the `npm create-react-app` command.
In this project, I wanted to use Tailwind CSS so I installed and used Craco as showed in the [Tailwind Setup Documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app).

But since then my js code doesn't compile at all.

I would like to know how to fix this problem and associate a compiler to Craco for my js code such as babel.

Here are my scripts set in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "craco start",
  "build": "craco build",
  "test": "craco test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

This is my craco.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
style: {
  postcss: {
    plugins: [
      require('tailwindcss'),
      require('autoprefixer'),
    ],
  },
},
}
```

Comment: You need to add build style in the scripts:     "build:style": "tailwind build src/styles/index.css -o src/styles/tailwind.css",

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
module.exports = {
  style: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [require('tailwindcss'), require('autoprefixer')],
    },
  },
  webpack: {
    configure: {
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            type: 'javascript/auto',
            test: /\.woff2$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                  name: '[name].[ext]',
                  outputPath: 'fonts/',
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
};
```